# Is it better to have a "How to install Windows 10 alongside..." wiki?

Tags: discussion, support

Windows 10 questions are increasing. I think someone should write a comprehensive post like [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) but for Windows 10 so that we can direct all "How do I install Windows 10 alongside Ubuntu" sort of questions to that post.

Or since there is not much (?) difference in Windows 8 vs Windows 10 should we use the [same](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) for Windows 10 as well?

I really feel something has to be done with Windows 10 ;)

Comment: I think the correct way is to rename that question and add there "or Windows 10". I see no difference to install Ubuntu with 8 or 10.

Comment: @Pilot6 I too feel like that.

Comment: Just remove 8... UEFI is more than enoght

Comment: @Braiam hmm Most people don't google UEFI...

Comment: @Tim that's interesting. Most OEM's market it as such, which is why seems it should be like that. Do you know something that would prove otherwise?

Comment: @Braiam https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=Install%20Windows%208%2C%20UEFI&cmpt=q&tz=Etc%2FGMT

Comment: https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=Ubuntu%20UEFI%2C%20Ubuntu%20Windows%208

Comment: @Tim are you aware that that graphic kind of prove my point... and even then you are comparing "UEFI" vs "Windows 8" without Ubuntu

Comment: @Braiam see the second one.

Answer (score 1):

After several iterations the title now reads:

> Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows (system) with UEFI

I think the "system" part after Windows is implied... that covers any (UEFI ^ Windows) installation for the foreseeable future.